# Constructing functions with multiple methods inside a closure, and the error "syntax: local variable T cannot be used in closure declaration"

Tags: types, scope, closures, julia, metaprogramming

I'm working on a Julia function that constructs a function with multiple methods inside a closure and return that. To simplify (the actual construction involves multiple non-trivial custom types), it looks like this:

```
function constructF(g::Function, n::Int)

    v = [g]
    for i in 2:n
        gi(x) = ForwardDiff.derivative(v[i - 1], x)
        v = vcat(v, gi)
    end

    for T in (Int, Float64) # two types but possibly more
        function f(x::T)
            acc = T(0)
            for i in 1:n
                acc += v[i](x)^i
            end
            acc
        end
    end

    return f
end
```

This kind of code is not supported as of Julia 1.1.1 and gives me

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: local variable T cannot be used in closure declaration
Stacktrace:
 [1] include(::String) at ./client.jl:403
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
in expression starting at /home/me/code/lang/julia/test.jl:3
```

The alternative would be the below but results in duplicated code.

```
function constructF(n::Int)

    v = [g]
    for i in 2:n
        gi(x) = ForwardDiff.derivative(v[i - 1], x)
        v = vcat(v, gi)
    end

    function f(x::Int)
        acc = Int(0)
        for i in 1:n
            acc += v[i](x)^i
        end
        acc
    end

    function f(x::Float64)
        acc = Float64(0)
        for i in 1:n
            acc += v[i](x)^i
        end
        acc
    end

    # ....

    return f
end
```

Is there a better way to write this? I've looked into metaprogramming but the documentation comes across as unintuitive and I'm not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just answered my own question. With some basic metaprogramming I can do:

```
function constructF(g::Function, n::Int)

    v = [g]
    for i in 2:n
        gi(x) = ForwardDiff.derivative(v[i - 1], x)
        v = vcat(v, gi)
    end

    for T in (:Int, :Float64)
        @eval function f(x::$T)
            acc = $T(0)
            for i in 1:$n
                acc += $v[i](x)^i
            end
            acc
        end
    end

    return f
end
```

Create a Julia expression, and evaluate it with each type Int, Float64, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You came across one answer, but not the Julian one.

```
function constructF(g::Function, n::Int)

    v = [g]
    for i in 2:n
        gi(x) = ForwardDiff.derivative(v[i - 1], x)
        v = vcat(v, gi)
    end

    function f(x::T<:Number)
        acc = zero(T)
        for i in 1:n
            acc += v[i](x)^i
        end
        acc
    end

    return f
end
```

If you are worried that not defining the specific methods will be slower, you don't yet understand the power of Julia's compiler. When you call this with an input, it will magically generate optimized code for the specific type.

Comment: I'll try that.. The only issue I have with this approach is that the actual code I'm working on uses a modified ForwardDiff that supports certain concrete types T where Real <: T <: Number , and not other subtyptes (ForwardDiff currently only supports T <: Real). I guess I can write it this way and have the function f error out on types that are not supported.

Comment: yeah, that approach makes sense.